# Setting different initializers for different connection strings of same context

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string, entity-framework-5

i use EF5 code-first and set my initializers in the config. I want to use more than one database of the same context-type in one application. My connection strings look as follows:

```
<add name="DatabaseProduction" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=DatabaseProduction; User Id=***; password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="DatabaseTest" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=DatabaseTest; User Id=***; password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I can use my contexts in the code like this

```
var _contextProd = new MyContext("DatabaseProduction");
var _contextTest = new MyContext("DatabaseTest");
```

The normal way to set the database initializer is the config file as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx). But as far as i understand i can set the initializer on a per-context basis but not one for each connection string. Wrong?

The question is: How to set e.g. a `DropCreateAllwaysInitializer` for the Test Database while having a `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsInitializer` on the Production Database?

============ Edit in answer to Gert's comment and for clearification ============

The way i usually define my Initializers is

```
<contexts>
  <context type=" Namespace.MyContext, MyAssembly">
    <databaseInitializer type="Namespace.MyCustomContextInitializer, MyAssembly" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

And I could for sure add a second `<context...>` here and define the initializer for **another context**. But how to tell which initializer is used at which connection string? My problem in other words:

1. The connection string has no knowledge about which context is there.
2. the context (in the context section) has no knowledge at which connection string it is linked
3. In code behind i tell the context which connection string to use
4. the initializer for a particular context seems to be kind of static for each context type.

Again, how do i define a particular initializer for a **pair of context and connection string**?

Comment: Can't you add a second `<context ... />` section to the config file within the `<contexts>` node? (So, one section each).

Comment: @GertArnold , i elaborated my question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to derive a context for each of your connection strings:

```
public class MyProductionContext : MyContext
{
  public MyProductionContext()
    : base( "DatabaseProduction" )
  {
  }
}
```

and

```
public class MyTestContext : MyContext
{
  public MyTestContext()
    : base( "DatabaseTest" )
  {
  }
}
```

You can then set your initializers for each of the derived contexts.

Comment: thats what i was planning to do as work-around. But i first want to wait and see if i missed some more elelgant way.

Comment: AFAIK, you've hit the limit of the configuration file support.

Comment: unfortunately there seems to be no cool solution. In my project i switched to Migrations. Not because they work well, but because they provide more flexibility. Kind of a sad state...